# Replace styles in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

I'm building out a simple site building tool using CKEditor.  The tool has the ability to choose from and set palettes, which should be reflected in the styles drop down of CKEditor.  However, it seems to me that styles cannot be overwritten in CKEditor.  The code I have at the moment is:

```
CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add( 'styles', [
  // Block-level styles
  { name: 'blah 1', element: 'h2', styles: { 'color': '#xxxxxx' } },
  { name: 'blah 2', element: 'h3', styles: { 'color': '#xxxxxx' } },
  { name: 'blah 3' , element: 'h4', styles: { 'color': '#xxxxxx' } },
  { name: 'blah 4' , element: 'h5', styles: { 'color': '#xxxxxx' } },
] );
CKEDITOR.config.stylesSet = 'styles';
```

Now, if I repeat this with new styles, I get:

```
ckeditor.js:232 Uncaught Error: [CKEDITOR.resourceManager.add] The resource name "styles" is already registered.
```

I've tried using CKEDITOR.replace, but this doesn't fix the issue.  I guess, the obvious solution is to iterate the style name with each use; style1, style2, style3... but that's not very resource friendly.  Does anyone have an actual solution for this?

Thanks,
Lee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured out a solution by always destroying the panel, if it exists, before re-creating it.  For instance:

```
if (CKEDITOR.instances['footer-' + i]) {
  CKEDITOR.instances['footer-' + i].destroy(true);
}
var editor = CKEDITOR.inline('footer-' + i, {
  stylesSet: [
    // Block-level styles
    { name: 'Blue Title', element: 'h2', styles: { 'color': 'Blue' } },
    { name: 'Red Title' , element: 'h3', styles: { 'color': 'Red' } },
    { name: 'Brown Title' , element: 'h4', styles: { 'color': 'Red' } },
    { name: 'Purple Title' , element: 'h5', styles: { 'color': 'Red' } }
  ]
});
```

Now, this does throw up a warning each time, saying:

```
[CKEDITOR] For more information about this error go to http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_errors-section-editor-incorrect-destroy
```

However, theres no clean way to do this otherwise with the CKEditor API, so since it works, I'm marking it as the answer.

Comment: Modifing style sets after editor initialization brings problems:
 1. [ACF](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_acf) creates its configuration based on provided styles - e.g. allows elements that are included in the styles definition.
 2. There is no information what to do with content already having styles that are being removed (should the content be removed or unstyled?)

The best way of dealing with this is to destroy the editor and create a new one with updated styles configuration. Also, post your example on JSFiddle/JSBin to make it easier to investigate the `incorrect-destroy` error.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried renaming **styles** to **default**?

I use this and it works, mine loads an external style file. But same array structure.

```
CKEDITOR.config.stylesSet = 'default:http://' + window.location.host + '/folder/fckeditor.styles.js';
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks for commenting.  If I do this, I get the error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getEditor' of undefined", which opens a whole new can of worms.

Comment: Did anything else change? I looked up that error, and it seems that error relates to the textarea not being found that you are calling in your replace command.